# Implement mem::swap in rust without std lib

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to write a mem::swap function without using any std lib functions. i am totally new to rust and still trying to make sense of how to use rust language.

below is my code

```
fn swap<T: std::fmt::Display>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
unsafe {
    // Give ourselves some scratch space to work with
    let mut t: &mut T = y;
    y = x;
    x = t;
    }
}
fn main() {
println!("Hello, world!");
let mut x = Box::new(5);
let mut y = Box::new(42);
let mut t = Box::new(0);
swap(&mut x, &mut y);
}
```

and i am facing below error

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:4:29
  |
1 | fn swap<T: std::fmt::Display>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
  |                                  -          - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
  |                                  |
  |                                  let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
4 |         let mut t: &mut T = y;
  |                             ^ assignment requires that `'2` must outlive `'1`
  |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
1 | fn swap<'a, T: std::fmt::Display>(x: &'a mut T, y: &'a mut T) {
  |         +++                           ++            ++
```

what does 'lifetime may not live long enough' mean ?
is there a simple way to write mem::swap code in rust ?

Comment: Important note: You're making a copy of the *reference*, not a copy of the *data*.

Comment: not 100% sure but remember that it is non-trivial (or even not possible?) to swap references within `Box<T>` if `T` is not `Sized`. Af for your example case, since `T` is `Sized` by default, @tadman 's last paragraph should solve the case.

Comment: @xcwang Yeah, there are certainly limitations, but I believe if you want to get really rough and tumble you can just swap the references in `unsafe` mode, but that's not ideal to implement yourself. I just figure there's a crate that does it properly out there somewhere if the built-in swap doesn't do it already.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `Copy` the data. The reference you're using is useless for this purpose. You need to actually alter what both `x` and `y` reference.

For example:

```rust
fn swap<T>(a: &mut T, b: &mut T) where T : Copy {
    (*a,*b) = (*b, *a)
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    let mut b = 2;
    
    swap(&mut a,&mut b);
    
    println!("a={}, b={}", a, b);
}
```

If you set up the conditions here, it's really a one-liner, Rust will figure out the "temporary" stuff for you. In fact, having a function to do this is actually kind of overkill, since you can just do that single line anywhere in your code as you would normally.

Maybe you want to optimize this around boxed values, taking `Box<T>` as an argument instead, in which case you could swap references within the box instead of copying, but that's a specialization.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am implementing a simple OS using rust and so i can not use any std lib components. currently i am writing a linked list database as part of the rust kernel and i had to do a swap at some point `std::mem::swap(&mut cur, self);`
so had to implement this swap without std::mem:swap()

Comment: i am getting below error with your suggested code.

'error[E0277]:` the trait bound `ListNode<T>: core::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
`71 |         swap(&mut cur, self);
      |         ^^^^ the trait  core::marker::Copy is not implemented for ListNode<T>`

Comment: Did you `#[derive(Copy)]` for your `ListNode` and constrain `T` likewise with `where T : Copy`? If you want to do a simple swap without cloning, that object and all contained objects need to be `Copy`, which is a way of declaring that they can be moved around arbitrarily without concern for internals. Some types, like `String`, aren't able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `core::ptr::swap` to swap raw pointers `*mut T`.

```
use core::ptr::swap;

fn custom_swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    unsafe {
        (x as *mut T).swap(y as *mut T);
    }
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let mut x = Box::new(5);
    let mut y = Box::new(42);

    println!("x={}, y={}", x, y);

    custom_swap(&mut x, &mut y);

    println!("x={}, y={}", x, y);
}
```

output

```
Hello, world!
x=5, y=42
x=42, y=5
```